# Filter by Bundle Drupal 8 Link Autocomplete

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, autocomplete, drupal-8

Does anyone know how to limit the autocomplete suggestions of Link Fields to only certain bundles -- not globally, but per Link Field  instance? I nearly found a solution in customizing https://github.com/minnur/Alter-Entity-Autocomplete , but this is global for all autocompletes, and I need to get the calling Link Field instance somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with hook form alter:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // if $form_id ==  'xyz'
  $form['field_mylink']['widget'][0]['uri']['#selection_handler']="default:node";
  $form['field_mylink']['widget'][0]['uri']['#selection_settings']=[
    'target_bundles'=>['article'=>'article', 'page'=>'page'], //etc
  ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following Drupal contributed module to solve the issue:

[Link Field Autocomplete Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_field_autocomplete_filter)

The module adds a Link Field configuration for filtering the allowed
content types in the autocomplete field.

You can install the module manually with the drupal core **Update Manager module** (must be enabled) using the Drupal backend:
http://yourSite/admin/reports/updates/install
and follow the instructions there.

Using Drush, you can install it with:

```
drush dl link_field_autocomplete_filter; // download
drush en link_field_autocomplete_filter; // enable the module
```

You can also us Composer to download the module:

```
composer require drupal/link_field_autocomplete_filter
```

Simply enable the module, and a series of checkboxes (one for each content type) will appear in the Link Field field-instance configuration form. If you check none, then all content types will appear as suggestions in the autocomplete. Otherwise only those checked will appear.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: Excuse me, but I did just that! This is not a link only answer! I named the Drupal Module and I quoted the function of the module with an exact description!  Yes, the link could change, though this is very unlikely. That is why I named the module.  In that case it is possible to google the name of the module.  Similarly, if I posted the entire code, the validity of the the answer could change in the future.

Comment: as it stands your answer provides no information if your becomes invalid, this is not seen as best practice on stack overflow

Comment: The answer provides the **name of the contributed drupal module**, and what it does. What else would you want? I already explained. Do you actually want me to remove the link and provide less information? Please explain what extra information you would want. It would certainly not be appropriate to post the entire module code.

Comment: @jmux if you could add a bit about how to use it and how it addresses your own question - that'd be great...

Comment: Drupal users are really going to laugh at the verbosity of the edited version.

Comment: Except it now explains (at a first glance) - a link including actual user instructions, no? Why is being helpful laughable? If I posted something here and said "use X" - it doesn't necessarily follow everyone *knows* how to use X or why they should bother looking at X. Once you add more such as "X solves it because, you can install it like this, and you configure it like this" - that's a more useful answer for *everyone* - no?

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The terse version was all that was needed. If a user is asking the question above, he or she will know how to find a contributed module and install it.  This was not a Drupal kindergarden question. Furthermore, links to Drupal modules will not change: it would break the whole Drupal update system. I finding it interesting  that the commenters seem not normally to answer Drupal questions themselves (both seem to be python programmers), nor did any of them actually add relevant information, as is customary.